# Percentile using SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 columns in my data set:

1. Monetary
2. Recency
3. Frequency

I want to create 3 more columns like M_P, R_Q, F_Q containing the percentile value of each of the values of Monetary, Recency, and Frequency using SQL.

Thank you in advance.

```
Customer_ID    Frequency Recency    Monetary    R_Q     F_Q        M_Q
112                 1      39          7.05      0.398   0.789    0.85873
143                 1      23          0.1833    0.232  0.7895   0.1501
164                 1      52          0.416      0.508   0.789  0.295
123                 1      118          1.1        0.98   0.789  0.52
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: do u want just to divide the columns by 100? Give some sample data and expected output. Also mention database version

Comment: I want the percentile rank of each of the value.

Comment: I am using Spark SQL editor.

Comment: How is this "percentile rank" calculated? Why it's `0.789` for `Frequency 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is the ANSI standard function `ntile()`:

```
select t.*,
       ntile(100) over (order by monetary) as percentile_monetary,
       ntile(100) over (order by recency) as percentile_recency,
       ntile(100) over (order by frequency) as percentile_frequency
from t;
```

This is available in most databases.

You can calculate the percentile using `rank()` and `count()`.  Depending on how you want to handle ties and whether you want values from 1-100 or 0-100, the following should a good starting point:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + rank_monetary * 100.0 / cnt) as percentile_monetary,
       (1 + rank_recency * 100.0 / cnt) as percentile_recency,
       (1 + rank_frequency * 100.0 / cnt) as percentile_frequency
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over () as cnt,
             rank() over (order by monetary) - 1 as rank_monetary,
             rank() over (order by recency) - 1 as rank_recency,
             rank() over (order by frequency) - 1 as rank_frequency
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: @Olay . . . Spark has supported window functions and `ntile()` for a while (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html).

Comment: ntile() is giving the integer values as 1, 2.... so on. What I want is the rank percentile as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, Could you explain me what (1 + rank_monetary * 100.0 / cnt) is doing.

Comment: It is converting the ranks to a value between 1 and 100.